# whyy output showing : undefined undefined ( Java Script )

Tags: javascript

```
function Book(title, author, isbn, stock, cost) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.isbn = isbn;
  this.stock = stock;
  this.cost = cost;
  this.summary = function () {
    `${this.title} by ${this.author} (ISBN: ${this.isbn}) costs $ ${this.cost}`;
  };
  this.isAvailable = function () {
    this.stock > 0
      ? `${this.title} is available`
      : `${this.title} is not available at the moment`;
  };
}

const product = new Book(
  "The Design of Everyday Things",
  "Don Norman",
  "978 - 0 - 465 - 05571 - 5",
  10,
  17.99
);
console.log(product.summary());
console.log(product.isAvailable());
```

It has to print:

"The Design of Everyday Things by Don Norman (ISBN: 978 - 0 - 465 - 05571 - 5) costs $17.99"

"The Design of Everyday things is available"

Comment: You have to use `return` to get a result returned by a normal function call.

Comment: Use linters like [ESLint](//eslint.org/play) or [JSHint](//jshint.com) to find problems with your code immediately. Relevant linter warning: _“Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression.”_.

Answer (score 2):

You're not returning anything in your functions:

```js
function Book(title, author, isbn, stock, cost) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.isbn = isbn;
  this.stock = stock;
  this.cost = cost;
  this.summary = function () {
    return `${this.title} by ${this.author} (ISBN: ${this.isbn}) costs $ ${this.cost}`;
  };
  this.isAvailable = function () {
    return this.stock > 0
      ? `${this.title} is available`
      : `${this.title} is not available at the moment`;
  };
}

const product = new Book(
  "The Design of Everyday Things",
  "Don Norman",
  "978 - 0 - 465 - 05571 - 5",
  10,
  17.99
);
console.log(product.summary());
console.log(product.isAvailable());
```

Using arrow functions, you can skip the return keyword if you prefer:

```js
function Book(title, author, isbn, stock, cost) {
  this.title = title;
  this.author = author;
  this.isbn = isbn;
  this.stock = stock;
  this.cost = cost;
  this.summary = () =>
    `${this.title} by ${this.author} (ISBN: ${this.isbn}) costs $ ${this.cost}`;
  
  this.isAvailable = () =>
    this.stock > 0
      ? `${this.title} is available`
      : `${this.title} is not available at the moment`;
}

const product = new Book(
  "The Design of Everyday Things",
  "Don Norman",
  "978 - 0 - 465 - 05571 - 5",
  10,
  17.99
);
console.log(product.summary());
console.log(product.isAvailable());
```

Comment: i have used  :  return `${this.title} by ${this.author} (ISBN: ${this.isbn}) costs $ ${this.cost}`